# How Can I Place A MYSQL Database Record In A Variable With PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I need some assistance with my code here. I'm using a mail() function to send a welcome email to a registrant.

My mailer script looks like this:

```html
<?php

$to = print require("includes/email.php");

$subject = "This is where I have my subject";

$txt = "Greetings
  "."\n"."
  Thank you for registering.
  "."\n"."
  This is some of my text
  "."\n"."
  Best Regards
  Admin";
$headers = "From: email@domain.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);

header("Location: pay.php");

?>
```

and my includes/email.php code looks like this:

```html
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = 'SELECT email_address FROM table WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM `table`)';

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo $row['email_address'];
}}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Now I want my $to variable to have the email_address record from my database and for the mail() function to send an email to that email when the mailer script is run. When I run the script, an email is displayed on the screen and no email is sent but everything works when I manually put an email address on the $to variable. How can I successfully get the script to send the email to the requested email on the database?

Answer (score 1):

```
$to = print require("includes/email.php");
```

Will be with no print.

```
$to = require("includes/email.php");
```

And you have to use `return` instead of `echo` in the `includes/email.php` file.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    return $row['email_address'];
}
```